# First half of plots is missing

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, gnuplot

I want to draw some functions with gnuplot. It works well, but the first half is missing and I don't know why.

```
\begin{figure}[htpb]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=0.8\textwidth, xlabel={Anzahl der Prozessoren}, ylabel={Speedup}, xmin=1, xmax=4096, ymin=0, ymax=30, xmode = log, log basis x={2},xticklabel=\pgfmathparse{2^\tick}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}]
\addplot gnuplot[black, solid, raw gnuplot,id=bal,mark=none,very thick]{
set xrange [0:4096];
set yrange [0:30];
p = 0.5;
f(x)=1/((1-p) + p/x);
plot f(x)};
\addplot gnuplot[black, dashed, raw gnuplot,id=bal,mark=none,very thick]{
set xrange [0:4096];
set yrange [0:30];
p = 0.8;
f(x)=1/((1-p) + p/x);
plot f(x)};
\addplot gnuplot[black, dotted, raw gnuplot,id=bal,mark=none,very thick]{
set xrange [0:4096];
set yrange [0:30];
p = 0.9;
f(x)=1/((1-p) + p/x);
plot f(x)}; 
\addplot gnuplot[black, loosely dotted, raw gnuplot,id=bal,mark=none,very thick]{
set xrange [0:4096];
set yrange [0:30];
p = 0.95;
f(x)=1/((1-p) + p/x);
plot f(x)};     
\legend{%
P = 50\%,
P = 80\%,
P = 90\%,
P = 95\%,
}           
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\caption{Speedup nach Amdahla'sches Gesetz}
\label[figure]{fig:amdahls_law_speedup}
\end{figure}
```

My result is this:

[image]

But it should be like this:

[image]

I am new with pgfplots. So maybe the code contains redundant data too. But why is the first part of the plots missing?

Comment: Just to say that gnuplot is not required for plotting your stuff...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This happens because there are no valid samples in the first half of your plot.

`gnuplot` by default uses 100 samples, starting with the first number in the sampling range and dividing the range equally in linear space. That means that in your case, you have samples at `0`, `41.4`, `82.8`, etc. The first sample evaluates to `NaN` because of the division by zero in your equation.

A quick fix would be to set the range to `1:4096`, ensuring that you get  a valid sample at the start. However, this wouldn't result in an accurate representation of your equation, since almost all samples are in the upper regions of your graph. A better approach is to also use `set logscale x;` in the `gnuplot` options to evenly spread the samples in logarithmic space:

[image]

---

In this case, there's no need to use `gnuplot` at all. This plot can be generated using only the built-in PGF math engine:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width=0.8\textwidth,
    xlabel={Anzahl der Prozessoren},
    ylabel={Speedup},
    domain = 1:4096,
    xmin=1, xmax=4096,
    ymin=0, ymax=30,
    xmode = log,
    log basis x={2},
    log ticks with fixed point
]
\addplot [black, very thick]{
1/((1-0.5) + 0.5/x)
};
\addplot [black, very thick, dashed]{
1/((1-0.8) + 0.8/x)
};
\addplot [black, very thick, dotted]{
1/((1-0.9) + 0.9/x)
};
\addplot [black, very thick, loosely dotted]{
1/((1-0.95) + 0.95/x)
};;     
\legend{%
P = 50\%,
P = 80\%,
P = 90\%,
P = 95\%,
}           
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very good explained answer! It works now. Can you tell me how you make ticks only for 2,8,32,128,512,2048 ? I have all from 1 to 4096 and it will be covered at the end.

Comment: @user2514411: PGFPlots automatically reduces the number of ticks if the labels would get too dense. If this doesn't happen for you, could you open a new question that includes a minimal example demonstrating the problem?

Answer (score 6):

A pure `pgfplots` solution might be also efficient and faster to type

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{semilogxaxis}[grid,log basis x={2},xticklabel=\pgfmathparse{2^\tick}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult},enlarge x limits = false,width=0.8\textwidth, xlabel={Anzahl der Prozessoren}, ylabel={Speedup}, xmin=1, ymin=0, legend pos=north west]
  \addplot [black, solid,mark=none,very thick,domain=1:4096]{1/((1-0.5) + 0.5/x)};
  \addplot [black, dashed,mark=none,very thick,domain=1:4096]{1/((1-0.8) + 0.8/x)};
  \addplot [black, dotted,mark=none,very thick,domain=1:4096]{1/((1-0.9) + 0.9/x)};
  \addplot [black, loosely dotted, mark=none,very thick,domain=1:4096]{1/((1-0.95) + 0.95/x)};
  \legend{%
P = 50\%,
P = 80\%,
P = 90\%,
P = 95\%,
}
\end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Note that the important plotting parameter to avoid log(0) is `domain=min:max` and NOT `xmin,xmax`.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I actually get a `Dimension too large` error when I try to run this code. I suspect your problem is that you have a `p/x` term; as `x->0` this term will become difficult to compute. Change the x limits in your gnuplots to `[1:4096]`. This works for me:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htpb]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=0.8\textwidth, xlabel={Anzahl der Prozessoren}, ylabel={Speedup}, xmin=1, xmax=4096, ymin=0, ymax=30, xmode = log, log basis x={2},xticklabel=\pgfmathparse{2^\tick}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}]
\addplot gnuplot[black, solid, raw gnuplot,id=bal1,mark=none,very thick]{
set xrange [1:4096];
set yrange [0:30];
p = 0.5;
f(x)=1/((1-p) + p/x);
plot f(x)};
\addplot gnuplot[black, dashed, raw gnuplot,id=bal2,mark=none,very thick]{
set xrange [1:4096];
set yrange [0:30];
p = 0.8;
f(x)=1/((1-p) + p/x);
plot f(x)};
\addplot gnuplot[black, dotted, raw gnuplot,id=bal3,mark=none,very thick]{
set xrange [1:4096];
set yrange [0:30];
p = 0.9;
f(x)=1/((1-p) + p/x);
plot f(x)}; 
\addplot gnuplot[black, loosely dotted, raw gnuplot,id=bal4,mark=none,very thick]{
set xrange [1:4096];
set yrange [0:30];
p = 0.95;
f(x)=1/((1-p) + p/x);
plot f(x)};     
\legend{%
P = 50\%,
P = 80\%,
P = 90\%,
P = 95\%,
}           
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
% \caption{Speedup nach Amdahla'sches Gesetz}
% \label[figure]{fig:amdahls_law_speedup}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]